# Unable to get access token after deploying Outlook Add-in SSO on Azure

Tags: azure, office365, single-sign-on, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have created one Office add-in for Outlook using "Office Add-in Task Pane project supporting single sign-on" option with "yo office" command.

And register the app in azure using "npm run configure-sso" command.
When I run this add-in locally it is working fine. Also I am able to get access token from bootstrap token to execute GRAPH API.

After that I am creating build version of Outlook add-in using "npm run build". And have deployed build files on Azure web app.

Also changed localhost 3000 URL with Azure web app URL in manifest.xml file.

When I tried to access the production version of build in Outlook, it is not allow to get access token for executing graph API. It is returning the default page html content response instead of JSON response.

I expecting the access token using azure web app URL deployed for Outlook Add-in SSO. Or Provide me steps to deploy the Outlook Add-in SSO on Azure.

Comment: Can you share exact API/code snapshot your are calling to get access token and result of the API. 
Also instructions to create a sample SSO app are available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/pnp-officeaddins/outlook-add-in-sso-aspnet/ and troubleshooting available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins#errors-on-the-server-side-from-azure-active-directory .

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your add-in with a valid URL in the `WebApplicationInfo` section, see [Enable single sign-on (SSO) in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#configure-the-add-in) for more more information.

The URI of the add-in should be the same URI (including the api: protocol) that you used when registering the add-in with the Microsoft identity platform. The domain part of this URI must match the domain, including any subdomains, used in the URLs in the `<Resources>` section of the add-in's manifest and the URI must end with the client ID specified in the `<Id>` element.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Everything is configured properly in manifest.xml according to azure web app URL. It is working fine when I use localhost:3000 URL but not working when I use azure web app URL after deploying build.